# Oracle in-memory db for unit test

Tags: mysql, oracle, unit-testing, in-memory-database

Recently, I got a task to do all the unit test for persistence layer. We have connection with MySQL and Oracle db, MySQL is done by H2, but oracle never happens on H2, it seems the dialect is not supported by h2. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean that your Oracle SQL commands or schema designs are invalid for H2?

For the schema, your h2 tables could use slightly different datatypes that are close enough.

For the different SQL syntax I would suggest trying to change your oracle SQL to use standard SQL that is supported by all database vendors.